# run Javascript-jquery function on two classes with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class

i have this Jquery photos slider script to slide photos on my website:

```
function Slider() {
    $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

    var sc=$(".slider img").size();
    var count=2;

    setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);
    $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

    if (count==sc) {
        count=1;
    }else{
        count=count+1;
    }
    },6500);
}
```

the function script runs only on the 1st "slider" class ,how can i run it properly on both classes at the same time?
the HTML classes are rather the same,div's with images between them.
thanks.

Comment: IDs can't start with number : http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: sure they can, since HTML5 .
http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: My bad, just learned something. Thanks! Although CSS selectors such as `div#25` won't work, need to use `div[id='25']`.